# How to position img element in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a block:

```
<section id="why">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <img src="img/image.png" alt="image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.container` have a margins of left and right, and i can't position image on left of body.
I need to pull image on left of body, and i need to make it responsive.

[it looks like this](http://cs539410.vk.me/u209513683/docs/fd219b94a6ef/img.jpg?extra=H_-nNBhUfXMOqYxOcRx6AyCpJN8IzKtkK-cejJBrjKUccK-dG13BgAn2I1sxWGrq8BmhslFIL-1MBRStoBEoRwHx54NmNQ)

Comment: given link is broken.

Comment: You are avoid container class in this case

Answer (score 0):

To make an img responsive use this:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

The .container has a padding of 15px on each side. By using a tool like Chrome Inspector, you can see the styles that each div has.

If not inspector, try removing each div that you have, one at a time and seeing how each one works. The time it took to ask this question, you could have narrowed it down by simply experimenting.

The official website is more than useful, is very well-documented, and it will clear up a lot of things if you take a little bit to read through it.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

You don't need the container, row or col divs.

```
<section id="why" class="text-left">
    <img src="img/image.png" alt="image">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```
<div id="why" class="pull-left">
   <img src="..." class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

you will now have a responsive image. But take note that the class img-responsive by default is display: block. if you want to resize the image, just set the width and height of the image.